# Disabling animations on WP7 ListPicker

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

When clicking on a `ListPicker` control, the full-screen list picker appears in a "venetian blind" style animation.  The same happens when dismissing the control.

Is there any way to turn this off (other than hacking the Silverlight Toolkit source code)?

Answer (score 0):

The animations are part of the default templates for the headers.

If you use your own template you'll lose the animations.

Comment: I am using my own HeaderTemplate and the animations are still happening...  `<toolkit:ListPicker Header="foo" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerHeaderTemplate}"/>`, and here's the header template: `<DataTemplate x:Key="ListPickerHeaderTemplate"> <Grid/> </DataTemplate>`